# Xcode can't verify the identity of the server "github.com", Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

[image]

Sorry for the dumb question, but I've been getting this on Xcode.  I'm not sure if it's because I updated to Mountain Lion or not.  Every time I click continue, I just get the same message and it never proceeds.  I am able to pull or push from the command line however.  Does anyone know how to solve this?  Thanks!

Comment: Still getting this? It suggests github's ssl cert expired on one of their load balancers, which could easily have been a transient problem on their end. Could also be something odd local.

Comment: @Christopher yup, still getting it.  Lol, not sure what to do still.

Comment: VonC's answer get you anywhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just click "Show Certificate", unfold the disclosure arrow and set the "Trust" dropdown option menu to "Always Trust". Accept and re-enter your password if asked. It should be fine now. (Sorry for not being more precise, but I don't have the Certificate window under my eyes right now.)

Comment: I did this and it didn't make a difference :(

Comment: It continues to ask on every push

Comment: For me it finally works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

None of the certificates in the CA chain for GitHub appears to have just expired or be closed to expire.

This [article](http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html) (on rail app, but also relevant here) suggests:

- [install MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php)
- use OpenSsl
- if have a directory `/opt/local/etc/openssl`:

```
$ cd /opt/local/etc/openssl
$ sudo curl -O http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
$ sudo mv cacert.pem cert.pem
$ setenv SSL_CERT_FILE /opt/local/etc/openssl/cacert.pem
```

Comment: http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?2876-Environment-Variables-in-Mountain-Lion on environment variables on Mountain Lion

Comment: FYI this happened this happened for me after I installed the GUI client for git on mac...

Answer (score -1):

Anyone facing this issue, quit your proxy and try again.