# Xcode can't verify the identity of a repository hosted on "github.com"

Tags: xcode, github, ssl-certificate

Intermittently experiencing this issue, usually on first try for the day. Do I need to upgrade my certificate(s)? How dangerous is it to choose Always Trust, in this situation?

[image: XCode error]

Comment: What protocol are you using to connect to github.com?

Comment: Under Xcode/Accounts I see I am using https with User Name and Password auth

Comment: Then what certificate is Xcode talking about?  The HTTPS certificate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12099727/2603230

Answer (score 2):

This may occur if you have any web proxy software running. This may modify the connection which will then give out this error.
[The error message that i faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7bS3.png)
Easy fix is to force quit your web proxy tools and then retry again.